# how to access the Istio ingress gateway from mac

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop, istio-gateway

I started a kubernetes cluster with Docker Desktop for Mac. I then installed Istio on the cluster and followed the steps to create Istio ingress gateway following steps in [Open the application to outside traffic](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#ip). At this point, I have:

```
(base) ~/istio/istio-1.16.1 $ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
default        details                ClusterIP      10.105.143.37    <none>        9080/TCP                                                                     5h5m
default        kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                                                                      6h16m
default        productpage            ClusterIP      10.106.2.22      <none>        9080/TCP                                                                     5h5m
default        ratings                ClusterIP      10.111.217.64    <none>        9080/TCP                                                                     5h5m
default        reviews                ClusterIP      10.104.251.134   <none>        9080/TCP                                                                     5h5m
istio-system   istio-egressgateway    ClusterIP      10.99.102.205    <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                                                               6h15m
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.108.135.209   localhost     15021:32723/TCP,80:32335/TCP,443:32040/TCP,31400:30864/TCP,15443:31429/TCP   6h15m
istio-system   istiod                 ClusterIP      10.101.35.195    <none>        15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP                                        6h15m
kube-system    kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                                                       6h16m
```

According the Istio document, for Docker Desktop, the ingress gateway host is set to 127.0.0.1.

```
$ export INGRESS_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

At this point, I could not access 127.0.0.1:80/productpage, neither 127.0.0.1:32335/productpage from my Mac. However according to the istio document, I should be able to access the page.

I understand that Docker for Desktop for Mac will setup a linuxkit VM and deploy the kubernetes on this VM. This VM has an internal ip 192.168.65.4, which I can not reach from my mac host. So the localhost from the kubectl get svc command above should really mean the linuxkit VM, not my mac host. So how to access the nodeport 32335 on the linuxkit VM from my mac host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use port forwarding to access the Istio ingress gateway from your Mac. First, find the port that the Istio ingress gateway is listening on.

Once you have the port number, run the following command to forward it to your local machine:

```
kubectl port-forward -n istio-system svc/istio-ingressgateway <PORT_NUMBER>
```